# Compare my variable with a csv file and get the matching value in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, variables, match, external

I have a javascript variable. I need to compare it to an external csv file and collect a matching value.

For example : my variable is blue. I have a file.csv formatted in this way :

"blue","top","110","in stock", "red","down","111","in stock" ...

The value I need to collect is always two positions after the variable. So if my variable is Blue, I need to get 110 as a new variable . If my variable is red I need to get 111 as a new variable so on.

How can I do this ? 
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick :

```
//test variables 
testarray =["blue","top","110","in stock", "red","down","111","in stock"]

//function
function testfunction(array, variable){
    var varindex = array.indexOf(variable)
    return array[varindex+2] 
}
//calling the function
testfunction(testarray, "blue")
```

Comment: How can I call the testarray values from the external csv file ? (first line) I can't put all the values into the script, is a 3mbyte csv

Comment: If you are using node.js you can probably read your file using fs.readFile() and import/parse the result into a variable.